# Let $f=x^p-\theta \in \mathbb{Q} [x]$ be irreducible, $p$ prime. Show that $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}} (f)$ is generated by two elements.

Tags: galois-theory

Let $f=x^p-\theta \in \mathbb{Q} [x]$ be irreducible for some $\theta \in \mathbb{Q}$, $p$ prime. Show that $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}} (f)$ is generated by two elements $\sigma$ and $\tau$ st.
$\sigma ^p=\tau ^{p-1}=1$ and $\sigma^k \tau=\tau \sigma$, where $\bar{k}$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$.

My thoughts go like this:
Let $\omega$ be a primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity. We can factor $f$ as $f=(x-\sqrt[p]{\theta})(x-\omega \sqrt[p]{\theta})...(x-\omega^{p-1}\sqrt[p]{\theta})$ so the splitting field for $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[p]{\theta})=L$.
So the elements of $\Gamma_{\mathbb{Q}} (f)$ will permute roots of $f$ and it is clear that this group will be generated by two elements.

Observe first extension $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$.
The minimal polynomial for $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ will be $p^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial $x^{p-1}+ ...+x+1$ and extension $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ is Galois.
Further, $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q})\cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ which is cyclic, so there is an element $\tau$ such that $\tau^{p-1}=1$.

Observe now extension $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)\subset L$.
The minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[p]{\theta}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ is $f$ ($f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ since any factor would contain $[\sqrt[p]{\theta}]^i$ in its coefficients for some $i <p$, but $[\sqrt[p]{\theta}]^i \notin \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ for $i<p$) and $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)\subset L$ is Galois extension $\Rightarrow |Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))|=p$ .
There is a theorem which tells that $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}(\omega))$ is cyclic so there is $\sigma$ such that $\sigma^p=1$.

Are these observations okay and how to proceed with last part?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx) for the Galois group. It is the semidirect product $\Bbb Z/p \rtimes (\Bbb Z/p)^{\times}$, so exactly what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing the Galois group of polynomials $x^n-a \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx)

Comment: I've read it, but i don't actually understan that approach, so I tried like this.

Comment: You can also see the approaches of others posts here, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3679839/galois-group-of-xp-a-over-mathbbq), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255309/compute-galois-group-of-splitting-field-of-xp-a-over-mathbb-q) with the semidirect product, for the Galois group of $x^p-a$.